# How to write Combination and Permutation from 2 numbers n and k in Ruby/Python?

Tags: python, ruby, combinations, permutation

For example, if I have 100 distinguishable dogs and I want to randomly pick 3 of them. With a pocket-size calculator, I would do 100C3 or something similar. How can I do this in Ruby and Python?

Edition 1: My questions were solved from Razvans and Riccardo Bucco solutions. (I flipped a fair coin once to decide to whom I give a check mark and to whom I give an upvote).

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: You want to select 3 dogs randomly or to compute the number of possible combinations of 3 dogs?

Comment: Can you show me how to do both?

Comment: Riccardo Bucco showed you how to calculate the combinations, I added an answer for the sampling

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be better to ask 2 question: one for Python and one for Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this in python:

```
from math import comb

n_combinations = comb(100, 3)
```

Similarly, for permutations:

```
from math import perm

n_permutations = perm(100, 3)
```

`perm` and `comb` can be used only with python > 3.8. For older versions of python please use these functions:

```
from math import factorial

def comb(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(k) // factorial(n - k)

def perm(n, k=None):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(n - (k or n))
```

Comment: I've got this error: module 'math' has no attribute 'comb'. I guess it's because the package version, isn't it?

Comment: One should also be able to use `itertools`.

Comment: @user15515518 Thanks for pointing it out. I added a couple of functions to be used for older python versions

Comment: @Chris I think it's a bad idea to generate all possible combinations/permutations just to count them.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Thanks, it worked. It so reminds me of school time when I had to use 
n! / k! * (n-k)! instead of just pressing nCk with a calculator haha.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has [combination](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/combination) (and [permutation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation)):

```
(0...100).to_a.combination(3).to_a
(0...100).to_a.permutation(3).to_a
```

But if you randomly want to pick 3 dogs from that array, there is [sample](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sample):

```
(0...100).to_a.sample(3)
```

Comment: I've got an error like this: 

Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:4: unexpected numeric constant
1: (0..100
       ^
Traceback:

How can I solve it?

Comment: @user15515518 Check your entry for typos, all three lines provided above are valid. The first two take a while to run, since they generate sets of ***all*** combinations and permutations.

Comment: If you want the counts rather than the actual combinations/permutations, you can define a couple of lambdas based on the definitional formulae: `num_perms = ->(n,k) { ((n-k+1)..n).inject(1, &:*) }` and `num_combos = ->(n,k) { mn = [k,n-k].min; num_perms[n,mn] / num_
perms[mn,mn] }`.  These yield `num_perms[100,3] # => 970200` and `num_combos[100,3] # => 161700` without having to generate the actual sets. @razvans, I didn't want to edit w/o your permission, but feel free to add this to your answer.

Comment: @pjs `(0..100).to_a.combination(3).size` calculates the number of combinations without generating them.

Comment: @Stefan I didn't know that, thanks.  Note, however, that the range `(0..100)` contains 101 elements, so you would have to amend your approach to either `(0...100)` or `(1..100)` to get the correct answer.

Comment: @pjs feel free to update. Thanks.

Comment: @razvans I think Stefan's comment negates the need to write lambdas or methods. I'll leave it as a comment for anybody who's interested.

Comment: @razvans Thank you. I couldn't do it on Paperspace platform but I managed to make it work on another site.Do you run your Ruby code locally?

Comment: @user15515518 Yes I have ruby installed on my local. For SO I sometime use https://replit.com/~

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's Array methods `combination`, `repeated_combination`, `permutation` and `repeated_permutation` all return Enumerators. Enumerators have a `size` method, which returns the size of the enumerator, or nil if it can't be calculated lazily. Happily in these cases they can, for example:

```
#How many ways to take 12 random dogs out of 1000 :
puts (1..1000).to_a.combination(12).size # 1953840414726664053684327000
```

Answer (score 0):

###### Selecting 3 random dogs out of 100 without replacement in python:

Assuming this pre-existing list:

```
dogs = [f'dog{i+1}' for i in range(100)]
# ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', ..., 'dog100']
```

You could use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences)

```
import random
random.sample(dogs, k=3)
```

possible output: `['dog56', 'dog13', 'dog59']`